# ajax settimeout to refresh div

Tags: ajax, browser, crash, settimeout

I am displaying a graph using jQplot to monitor data.
To refresh the div holding the graph, I invoke an ajax call every 5 seconds (see JavaScript excerpt below).
On the server, a PHP script retrieves the data from a database.
On success, the ajax call is reinvoked after 5 seconds with a JavaScript setTimeout(ajax,5000).
On error, the ajax call is retried 10 times with setTimeout(ajax,5000) before displaying an error message.
Monitoring XHR learns that the browser crashes after approximately 200 requests.
As a temporary remedy, a location.reload() is issued after 50 iterations to prevent the browser from crashing.
This works, but is not an ideal situation.
Any better solution to this problem is very much appreciated.

Thanks and regards, JZB

```
function ajax() {
  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: 'monitor.php',
    data : { x: id },
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: onDataReceived,
    error: onDataError
  });

  function onDataReceived(series) {
    $('#chartdiv_bar').html('');
    $.jqplot('chartdiv_bar', [series['initHits']], CreateOptions(series,'Inits'));

    errorcount = 0;
    setTimeout(ajax, 5000);
  }

  function onDataError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    errorcount++;
    if (errorcount == 10) {
      alert("No server response:\n\n" + textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
    } else {
      setTimeout(ajax, 5000);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're re-calling ajax() after a good or fail ajax call, you're starting multiple timers.  This is why your browser is crashing.

you may want to try to clear the current timer and then start the next timer

```
var t; //global
```

In each of your call back functions:

```
if(t)      
 clearTimeout(t);
t = setTimeout(ajax, 5000);
```

more info on timer here:  [w3 school](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Using clearTimeout as suggested does not solve the problem.
Monitoring XHR still shows requests building up until the browser crashes at approximately 200 requests.
I believe these are ajax requests rather then timer requests and I can't think of any other way than a page reload to clear them.
Again, suggestions for a solution are very much appreciated.

Comment: oh sorry that did not work.  Have you tried to remove the jqplot call from your code.  Maybe use an alert statement there instead.  just to rule out a problem with jqplot.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the jqplot call as suggested and the problem disappeared.

Apparently jqplot is the culprit and I found numerous entries referring to jqPlot memory leaks.

I use jQuery 1.6.4 and installed jqPlot Charts version 1.0.0b2_r792 which supposedly addresses memory leak issues.

Furthermore, I replaced

```
$('#chartdiv_bar').html('');
```

with

```
$('#chartdiv_bar').empty();
```

Thank you for your support.